# Cannot add array to another object in loop

Tags: javascript

I have a dataset consisting of columns of parents and children, and I want to loop through it to nest the children as an array of the parent object.

I have a loop like so:

```
for (let d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
    let i = data[d];

    //regular item (not a parent just append to new items as is)
    if (!i.is_parent && !i.is_child) {
       items.push(i);

     //parent -- here I want to nest children as property
    } else if (i.is_parent) {
       let parent = i;
       let children = [];  //for loading children into

       for (d = d+1;  data[d].is_child && data[d].parent_id === parent.parent_id; d++ ) {
            let child = data[d];
            console.log('child;', child); //printing ok
            children.push(child);
         } // end inner loop
      
       console.log('ending children:', children); //shows full array of children ok
       parent.children = children;  // <-----trying to add property with whole array here
       console.log('parent ending: ', parent); //<-----shows children: [] (empty)!!
       items.push(parent);
    }  
       
  } //end outer loop
```

The children console out just  fine, but after I try to add to parent, the property shows as an empty array [].

What am I missing?

Here's an sample of data:

```
[{cat_id: 3
hide_children: 0
id: 1128
is_child: 0
is_parent: 0
name: "nori"
parent: "nori"
parent_id: 1128
},
{
cat_id: 3
hide_children: 0
id: 122
is_child: 0
is_parent: 0
name: "onions, in general"
parent: "onions, in general"
},
{
cat_id: 3
children: []
hide_children: 0
id: 1396
is_child: 0
is_parent: 1
name: "a"
parent: "onions, specific"
parent_id: 1396
},
{
cat_id: 3
hide_children: 0
id: 36
is_child: 1
is_parent: 0
name: "chives"
parent: "onions, specific"
parent_id: 1396
}
]
```

Comment: Could you share an example of the data that you loop over?

Comment: I think your inner `d++` makes you skip an item in the outer loop. You "owe" a `d--` after the inner loop.

Comment: not a good idea to reuse a index variable in the inner loop. Avoid trouble!

Answer (score 0):

You have objects there. So you can not push in object.
You should ether turn object into array and push after, or work with objects directly.
It will look like this:

```js
    let data = [
        {
            cat_id: 3,
            hide_children: 0,
            id: 1128,
            is_child: 0,
            is_parent: 0,
            name: "nori",
            parent: "nori",
            parent_id: 1128,
        },
        {
            cat_id: 3,
            hide_children: 0,
            id: 122,
            is_child: 0,
            is_parent: 0,
            name: "onions, in general",
            parent: "onions, in general",
        },
        {
            cat_id: 3,
            children: [],
            hide_children: 0,
            id: 1396,
            is_child: 0,
            is_parent: 1,
            name: "a",
            parent: "onions, specific",
            parent_id: 1396,
        },
        {
            cat_id: 3,
            hide_children: 0,
            id: 36,
            is_child: 1,
            is_parent: 0,
            name: "chives",
            parent: "onions, specific",
            parent_id: 1396,
        }
    ]
    
    let items = [];
    
    for (let p = 0; p < data.length; p++) {
        if(data[p].is_parent){
            for(let c = 0; c < data.length; c++){
                if(data[p].id === data[c].parent_id){
                    items = [{
                        ...data[p],
                        children: data[c]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
console.log(items)
```